# Issue storing the size of a queue in C++

Tags: c++, size, queue

I'm trying to store the size of a queue in an int in C++. I'm pretty new to this, but I don't know what I could be doing wrong. I get this error message:

> "error: request for member ‘size’ in ‘free_men’, which is of non-class type ‘int’ "

Here is the code:
I initialized the queue, and am just filling it with n numbers.

```
queue<int> free_men;
for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    free_men.push(i + 1);
}
int free_men = free_men.size();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the same variable name for both the `queue` and the `int`. Rename the `int` variable.

```
queue<int> free_men;
for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    free_men.push(i + 1);
}
int free_men_size = free_men.size();
```

Surprising though that the error message isn't more explicit.

Comment: I suppose it is likely only surprising that the more explicit part of the message wasn't noticed :)

Answer (score 2):

You have a duplicate variable name.

You will be seeing more than just the compiler message you mentioned, since it is illegal to redeclare `free_men` (as `int`) in the same scope.

```
queue<int> free_men;
for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    free_men.push(i + 1);
}
int number_of_free_men = free_men.size(); // NOTE fixed name clash
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two variables here, both with the same name in the same scope. If you change the last line to:

```
int free_men_size = free_men.size()
```

Things will likely work better.